# How to create a virtual data room with windows azure

Tags: .net, azure

I am quite new to application development, just starting out in fact. I wish to create a "virtual data room" that would enable multiple users securely access a set of files (total of about 10gb of data) and the data access should be logged as well.

The application would present an web-site based interface where users can access the said files via any standard web browser. And since I am most familiar with .NET and C#, that would be my choice of platform.

I am not quite familiar with the Azure platform, but I do have a strong understanding of basic programming concepts and have worked with C# .NET and Java.

What would be the best way to go about it? I am determined to use Azure since learning about the platform while developing is equally important to me.

I can't figure out how the various services such as Virtual machine, web site and cloud service are different. A link to a good resource would be helpful too.

But the first priority is to be able to build and deploy the application. I am open to all suggestions

Comment: Start with this tutorial http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/tutorials/web-site-with-sql-database/. It shows how to build and deploy an azure application.

Comment: Then you move into this http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/how-to-guides/blob-storage/

Comment: And finally this http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/support/trust-center/security/
:)

Comment: If you have worked with ASP.NET web sites then all that is different is you have a web site in Azzure and the files are stored in blobs rather than file system.  If you are using MemberShip for authentication then it gets set up differently.

Comment: Thanks Blam, this is good enough to get me started.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case you want to call it an answer.

If you have worked with ASP.NET web sites then all that is different is you have a web site in Azure and the files are stored in blobs rather than file system. If you are using MemberShip for authentication then it gets set up differently.